# Trouble parsing LARGE javascript object with for loop

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, parsing

I have this large javascript object:

```
{"raw": null, "entities": ["CLOUD14", "ABUSE2916-ARIN", "ADMIN2521-ARIN", "NOC11962-ARIN"], "asn_registry": "arin", "network": {"status": null, "handle": "NET-104-16-0-0-1", "name": "CLOUDFLARENET", "links": ["https://rdap.arin.net/registry/ip/104.16.0.0", "https://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-104-16-0-0-1"], "raw": null, "country": null, "ip_version": "v4", "start_address": "104.16.0.0", "notices": [{"description": "By using the ARIN RDAP/Whois service, you are agreeing to the RDAP/Whois Terms of Use", "links": ["https://www.arin.net/whois_tou.html"], "title": "Terms of Service"}], "end_address": "104.31.255.255", "remarks": [], "parent_handle": "NET-104-0-0-0-0", "cidr": "104.16.0.0/12", "type": null, "events": [{"action": "last changed", "timestamp": "2017-02-17T18:08:30-05:00", "actor": null}, {"action": "registration", "timestamp": "2014-03-28T10:30:55-04:00", "actor": null}]}, "objects": {"CLOUD14": {"status": null, "roles": ["registrant"], "handle": "CLOUD14", "entities": ["ABUSE2916-ARIN", "ADMIN2521-ARIN", "NOC11962-ARIN"], "links": ["https://rdap.arin.net/registry/entity/CLOUD14", "https://whois.arin.net/rest/org/CLOUD14"], "raw": null, "notices": null, "contact": {"kind": "org", "name": "Cloudflare, Inc.", "title": null, "phone": null, "role": null, "address": [{"type": null, "value": "101 Townsend Street\nSan Francisco\nCA\n94107\nUnited States"}], "email": null}, "events_actor": null, "remarks": [], "events": [{"action": "last changed", "timestamp": "2017-02-17T18:19:16-05:00", "actor": null}, {"action": "registration", "timestamp": "2010-07-09T13:10:42-04:00", "actor": null}]}, "ADMIN2521-ARIN": {"status": ["validated"], "roles": ["technical"], "handle": "ADMIN2521-ARIN", "entities": null, "links": ["https://rdap.arin.net/registry/entity/ADMIN2521-ARIN", "https://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/ADMIN2521-ARIN"], "raw": null, "notices": null, "contact": {"kind": "group", "name": "Admin", "title": null, "phone": [{"type": ["work", "voice"], "value": "+1-650-319-8930"}], "role": null, "address": [{"type": null, "value": "101 Townsend Street\nSan Francisco\nCA\n94107\nUnited States"}], "email": [{"type": null, "value": "rir@cloudflare.com"}]}, "events_actor": null, "remarks": [], "events": [{"action": "last changed", "timestamp": "2017-10-05T15:42:30-04:00", "actor": null}, {"action": "registration", "timestamp": "2011-04-19T15:11:36-04:00", "actor": null}]}, "ABUSE2916-ARIN": {"status": ["validated"], "roles": ["abuse"], "handle": "ABUSE2916-ARIN", "entities": null, "links": ["https://rdap.arin.net/registry/entity/ABUSE2916-ARIN", "https://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/ABUSE2916-ARIN"], "raw": null, "notices": null, "contact": {"kind": "group", "name": "Abuse", "title": null, "phone": [{"type": ["work", "voice"], "value": "+1-650-319-8930"}], "role": null, "address": [{"type": null, "value": "101 Townsend Street\nSan Francisco\nCA\n94107\nUnited States"}], "email": [{"type": null, "value": "abuse@cloudflare.com"}]}, "events_actor": null, "remarks": [], "events": [{"action": "last changed", "timestamp": "2017-02-17T18:11:38-05:00", "actor": null}, {"action": "registration", "timestamp": "2011-02-14T19:00:47-05:00", "actor": null}]}, "NOC11962-ARIN": {"status": ["validated"], "roles": ["noc"], "handle": "NOC11962-ARIN", "entities": null, "links": ["https://rdap.arin.net/registry/entity/NOC11962-ARIN", "https://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/NOC11962-ARIN"], "raw": null, "notices": null, "contact": {"kind": "group", "name": "NOC", "title": null, "phone": [{"type": ["work", "voice"], "value": "+1-650-319-8930"}], "role": null, "address": [{"type": null, "value": "101 Townsend Street\nSan Francisco\nCA\n94107\nUnited States"}], "email": [{"type": null, "value": "noc@cloudflare.com"}]}, "events_actor": null, "remarks": [], "events": [{"action": "last changed", "timestamp": "2017-02-17T18:15:44-05:00", "actor": null}, {"action": "registration", "timestamp": "2011-04-19T15:25:31-04:00", "actor": null}]}}, "asn_country_code": "US", "asn_date": "2014-03-28", "asn_cidr": "104.24.112.0/20", "nir": null, "query": "104.24.114.36", "asn": "13335"}
```

I am attempting to parse/dump the key value pairs into a list in a table on my dashboard but when I do a for loop such as

```
for (var key in myObject) {
  if (myObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(key + " -> " + myObject[key]);
  }
}
```

Unfortunately my output then becomes

```
0 -> { 1 -> " 2 -> r 3 -> a 4 -> w 5 -> " 6 -> : 7 ->   8 -> n ...
```

I seem to be pairing each first letter to a key. What exactly am I doing wrong here? I've tried several for loops (Written different ways) but I seem to get the same output. If you dump the object into this site: http://countwordsfree.com/jsonviewer and select "Tree Mode" that breakdown is similar to what I want to see (even though I don't care about the accordion/trees).

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you're reading in your javascript object as a string. Make sure it's an actual JS object (and don't use eval() to do so).

Comment: where does the object come from? did you JSON.parse(myObject) before looping??

Comment: The object is part of a bigger object which is a query I’m receiving from the Whois API. Im targeting this specific object within the larger one and attempting to parse it out. Does that answer your question???

Comment: can provide a JSFiddle?

Comment: @RobiminusMaximus - No, that does not answer my question. It was a yes or no question. If the answer is "no", then my response is, "well do it."

Comment: Your code works fine verbatim.. https://jsfiddle.net/abnu8c3r/1/ .. the only reason you would be getting this kind of error is if the data is a string and you have not parsed it with JSON.parse

Comment: Ok excellent thanks. @DauleDK here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ou9tsuxs/7/

Comment: @RobiminusMaximus run this line: `console.log(typeof myObject);`. That should tell you if myObject is, in fact, an object.

Comment: Thanks @Occam'sRazor I think I got it to work. I guess it was a string. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

> It seems you are trying to iterate `JSON string` instead of `JSON Object`.

**Output with JSON string :**

```js
var myObject = '{"raw": null, "entities": ["CLOUD14", "ABUSE2916-ARIN", "ADMIN2521-ARIN", "NOC11962-ARIN"], "asn_registry": "arin", "network": {"status": null, "handle": "NET-104-16-0-0-1", "name": "CLOUDFLARENET", "links": ["https://rdap.arin.net/registry/ip/104.16.0.0", "https://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-104-16-0-0-1"], "raw": null, "country": null, "ip_version": "v4", "start_address": "104.16.0.0", "notices": [{"description": "By using the ARIN RDAP/Whois service, you are agreeing to the RDAP/Whois Terms of Use", "links": ["https://www.arin.net/whois_tou.html"], "title": "Terms of Service"}], "end_address": "104.31.255.255", "remarks": [], "parent_handle": "NET-104-0-0-0-0", "cidr": "104.16.0.0/12", "type": null, "events": [{"action": "last changed", "timestamp": "2017-02-17T18:08:30-05:00", "actor": null}, {"action": "registration", "timestamp": "2014-03-28T10:30:55-04:00", "actor": null}]}, "objects": {"CLOUD14": {"status": null, "roles": ["registrant"], "handle": "CLOUD14", "entities": ["ABUSE2916-ARIN", "ADMIN2521-ARIN", "NOC11962-ARIN"], "links": ["https://rdap.arin.net/registry/entity/CLOUD14", "https://whois.arin.net/rest/org/CLOUD14"], "raw": null, "notices": null, "contact": {"kind": "org", "name": "Cloudflare, Inc.", "title": null, "phone": null, "role": null, "address": [{"type": null, "value": "101 Townsend Street\nSan Francisco\nCA\n94107\nUnited States"}], "email": null}, "events_actor": null, "remarks": [], "events": [{"action": "last changed", "timestamp": "2017-02-17T18:19:16-05:00", "actor": null}, {"action": "registration", "timestamp": "2010-07-09T13:10:42-04:00", "actor": null}]}, "ADMIN2521-ARIN": {"status": ["validated"], "roles": ["technical"], "handle": "ADMIN2521-ARIN", "entities": null, "links": ["https://rdap.arin.net/registry/entity/ADMIN2521-ARIN", "https://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/ADMIN2521-ARIN"], "raw": null, "notices": null, "contact": {"kind": "group", "name": "Admin", "title": null, "phone": [{"type": ["work", "voice"], "value": "+1-650-319-8930"}], "role": null, "address": [{"type": null, "value": "101 Townsend Street\nSan Francisco\nCA\n94107\nUnited States"}], "email": [{"type": null, "value": "rir@cloudflare.com"}]}, "events_actor": null, "remarks": [], "events": [{"action": "last changed", "timestamp": "2017-10-05T15:42:30-04:00", "actor": null}, {"action": "registration", "timestamp": "2011-04-19T15:11:36-04:00", "actor": null}]}, "ABUSE2916-ARIN": {"status": ["validated"], "roles": ["abuse"], "handle": "ABUSE2916-ARIN", "entities": null, "links": ["https://rdap.arin.net/registry/entity/ABUSE2916-ARIN", "https://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/ABUSE2916-ARIN"], "raw": null, "notices": null, "contact": {"kind": "group", "name": "Abuse", "title": null, "phone": [{"type": ["work", "voice"], "value": "+1-650-319-8930"}], "role": null, "address": [{"type": null, "value": "101 Townsend Street\nSan Francisco\nCA\n94107\nUnited States"}], "email": [{"type": null, "value": "abuse@cloudflare.com"}]}, "events_actor": null, "remarks": [], "events": [{"action": "last changed", "timestamp": "2017-02-17T18:11:38-05:00", "actor": null}, {"action": "registration", "timestamp": "2011-02-14T19:00:47-05:00", "actor": null}]}, "NOC11962-ARIN": {"status": ["validated"], "roles": ["noc"], "handle": "NOC11962-ARIN", "entities": null, "links": ["https://rdap.arin.net/registry/entity/NOC11962-ARIN", "https://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/NOC11962-ARIN"], "raw": null, "notices": null, "contact": {"kind": "group", "name": "NOC", "title": null, "phone": [{"type": ["work", "voice"], "value": "+1-650-319-8930"}], "role": null, "address": [{"type": null, "value": "101 Townsend Street\nSan Francisco\nCA\n94107\nUnited States"}], "email": [{"type": null, "value": "noc@cloudflare.com"}]}, "events_actor": null, "remarks": [], "events": [{"action": "last changed", "timestamp": "2017-02-17T18:15:44-05:00", "actor": null}, {"action": "registration", "timestamp": "2011-04-19T15:25:31-04:00", "actor": null}]}}, "asn_country_code": "US", "asn_date": "2014-03-28", "asn_cidr": "104.24.112.0/20", "nir": null, "query": "104.24.114.36", "asn": "13335"}';

for (var key in myObject) {
  if (myObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(key + " -> " + myObject[key]);
  }
}
```

**Output with JSON object :**

```js
var myObject = {"raw": null, "entities": ["CLOUD14", "ABUSE2916-ARIN", "ADMIN2521-ARIN", "NOC11962-ARIN"], "asn_registry": "arin", "network": {"status": null, "handle": "NET-104-16-0-0-1", "name": "CLOUDFLARENET", "links": ["https://rdap.arin.net/registry/ip/104.16.0.0", "https://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-104-16-0-0-1"], "raw": null, "country": null, "ip_version": "v4", "start_address": "104.16.0.0", "notices": [{"description": "By using the ARIN RDAP/Whois service, you are agreeing to the RDAP/Whois Terms of Use", "links": ["https://www.arin.net/whois_tou.html"], "title": "Terms of Service"}], "end_address": "104.31.255.255", "remarks": [], "parent_handle": "NET-104-0-0-0-0", "cidr": "104.16.0.0/12", "type": null, "events": [{"action": "last changed", "timestamp": "2017-02-17T18:08:30-05:00", "actor": null}, {"action": "registration", "timestamp": "2014-03-28T10:30:55-04:00", "actor": null}]}, "objects": {"CLOUD14": {"status": null, "roles": ["registrant"], "handle": "CLOUD14", "entities": ["ABUSE2916-ARIN", "ADMIN2521-ARIN", "NOC11962-ARIN"], "links": ["https://rdap.arin.net/registry/entity/CLOUD14", "https://whois.arin.net/rest/org/CLOUD14"], "raw": null, "notices": null, "contact": {"kind": "org", "name": "Cloudflare, Inc.", "title": null, "phone": null, "role": null, "address": [{"type": null, "value": "101 Townsend Street\nSan Francisco\nCA\n94107\nUnited States"}], "email": null}, "events_actor": null, "remarks": [], "events": [{"action": "last changed", "timestamp": "2017-02-17T18:19:16-05:00", "actor": null}, {"action": "registration", "timestamp": "2010-07-09T13:10:42-04:00", "actor": null}]}, "ADMIN2521-ARIN": {"status": ["validated"], "roles": ["technical"], "handle": "ADMIN2521-ARIN", "entities": null, "links": ["https://rdap.arin.net/registry/entity/ADMIN2521-ARIN", "https://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/ADMIN2521-ARIN"], "raw": null, "notices": null, "contact": {"kind": "group", "name": "Admin", "title": null, "phone": [{"type": ["work", "voice"], "value": "+1-650-319-8930"}], "role": null, "address": [{"type": null, "value": "101 Townsend Street\nSan Francisco\nCA\n94107\nUnited States"}], "email": [{"type": null, "value": "rir@cloudflare.com"}]}, "events_actor": null, "remarks": [], "events": [{"action": "last changed", "timestamp": "2017-10-05T15:42:30-04:00", "actor": null}, {"action": "registration", "timestamp": "2011-04-19T15:11:36-04:00", "actor": null}]}, "ABUSE2916-ARIN": {"status": ["validated"], "roles": ["abuse"], "handle": "ABUSE2916-ARIN", "entities": null, "links": ["https://rdap.arin.net/registry/entity/ABUSE2916-ARIN", "https://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/ABUSE2916-ARIN"], "raw": null, "notices": null, "contact": {"kind": "group", "name": "Abuse", "title": null, "phone": [{"type": ["work", "voice"], "value": "+1-650-319-8930"}], "role": null, "address": [{"type": null, "value": "101 Townsend Street\nSan Francisco\nCA\n94107\nUnited States"}], "email": [{"type": null, "value": "abuse@cloudflare.com"}]}, "events_actor": null, "remarks": [], "events": [{"action": "last changed", "timestamp": "2017-02-17T18:11:38-05:00", "actor": null}, {"action": "registration", "timestamp": "2011-02-14T19:00:47-05:00", "actor": null}]}, "NOC11962-ARIN": {"status": ["validated"], "roles": ["noc"], "handle": "NOC11962-ARIN", "entities": null, "links": ["https://rdap.arin.net/registry/entity/NOC11962-ARIN", "https://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/NOC11962-ARIN"], "raw": null, "notices": null, "contact": {"kind": "group", "name": "NOC", "title": null, "phone": [{"type": ["work", "voice"], "value": "+1-650-319-8930"}], "role": null, "address": [{"type": null, "value": "101 Townsend Street\nSan Francisco\nCA\n94107\nUnited States"}], "email": [{"type": null, "value": "noc@cloudflare.com"}]}, "events_actor": null, "remarks": [], "events": [{"action": "last changed", "timestamp": "2017-02-17T18:15:44-05:00", "actor": null}, {"action": "registration", "timestamp": "2011-04-19T15:25:31-04:00", "actor": null}]}}, "asn_country_code": "US", "asn_date": "2014-03-28", "asn_cidr": "104.24.112.0/20", "nir": null, "query": "104.24.114.36", "asn": "13335"};

for (var key in myObject) {
  if (myObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(key + " -> " + myObject[key]);
  }
}
```